# how do i display a list of tiles from cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

i have a firestore database having a collection named crypto and withing that few documents with 2 fields- name and price.
How do i get a itemlist with the name of my item on the main page and when I click the name a new page with the price.

The tutorials I am following on youtube are giving me errors as they are old and many functions are deprecated. also is there any good resource with code snippets for the recent version of flutter with firebase to learn from.?

Comment: Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include the code you've attempted and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
If this is what you are looking for then use the following as a body of your scaffold or you can use it in other widget if you want to.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('crypto')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Something went wrong');
              }

              if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                  ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Text("Loading");
              }
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs
                    .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> crypto = document.data();
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                            border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey)
                          ),
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: Text('${crypto['name']}'),
                            subtitle: Text('${crypto['price']}'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }),
```

Answer (score 0):

In scaffold body use Stream Builder and stream should `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('crypto').snapshots()` this will get all document in that collection as a snapshot.

in the builder

```
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
            return ListTile(...
            onTap: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) => SomeOtherPage(document: snapshot[index]),
                 ),
              });
        } else {
          return Center(
            child: Text(
                'Empty',
               ),
            );
          }
        },


class SomeOtherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot document;
  const SomeOtherPage({Key? key, required this.document}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SomeOtherPageState createState() => _SomeOtherPageState();
}
```

On the second page, you don't need StreamBuilder if you don't want the latest data from Fitrestore, if you want you can access it as previously but you don't have to use ListView.builder() you can use ListView() because you are only accessing one document `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('crypto').doc(widget.document.id).snapshots()` this will get only the document you have requested as a snapshot.